# Leibniz test is wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Maybe I am reading the mathese wrong but according to my book: If $a_n$ is positive and decreasing and $\,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0,\,$ then the alternating series converges.

So for example if I have $\,\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n},\,$ I know that diverges so $\,\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\,$ should also diverge but according to the Leibniz test it is decreasing and it's limit is zero so it should converge. What does this mean?

Comment: Why do you think the alternating series "should also diverge"? The answers in your earlier question are suggesting that since the harmonic series diverges, the alternating harmonic series cannot converge *absolutely* (not that it can't converge).

Comment: The series converges to $-\log 2$. However, the series would be a terrible way to try to approximate $\log 2$ because convergence is quite slow. We need to add up $2000$ terms to get $3$ decimal place accuracy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternating series $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ converges, as you note, conditionally, and by the Leiniz test. It *does not* converge absolutely. Please note that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \neq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac 1n$$

Alternating series are not equivalent to their non-alternating counterparts. The alternating series test, aka the Leibniz Test, is precisely for series like this: series that do not converge absolutely, but converge nonetheless. The fact that alternating terms are *negative* negates the divergence of the sum in the case of the absolute term.

Absolute convergence simply means the series consisting of the *absolute values* of the terms converges. It does not mean "definitely" converges.  A conditionally convergent series still very much converges, for a different reason, but converges just the same.

Comment: But the test says that it should converge.

Comment: @John The test says the series with  **with** the $(-1)^n$ converges, not the series **without** the $(-1)^n$.

Comment: But it doesn't converge, it only converges as an absolute value.

Comment: What do you mean? It is not *absolutely* convergent (ie, the series of the absolute values does not converge), but it does *conditionally* converge (ie, $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ has a limit when $N\to\infty$)

Comment: @John What do you mean by that?

Comment: Wait...wut? lol so absolutely convergent doesn't mean that it is absolutely convergent it just means that the absolute value does not converge?

Comment: @John A series $\sum a_k$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum |a_k|$ converges. It is conditionally convergent if $\sum a_k$ converges but $\sum |a_k|$ diverges.

Comment: "$\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent" means that the series $\sum |a_n|$ converges, ie $\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n| \to \ell$ when $N\to\infty$, for some $\ell\in \mathbb R_+$.

Comment: I really don't understand any of this but I will just memorize that this converges.

Comment: It's the definition: a series $\sum a_n$ is said to *converge* if $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ has a limit when $N$ goes to $\infty$. A series $\sum a_n$ is said to *converge absolutely* if the series of the absolute values, $\sum |a_n|$, converges (note that this is stronger: "absolutely convergent" implies "convergent"). If a series converges, but does not converge absolutely, it is said to converge *conditionally*.

Comment: It will begin to sink in. It does get very confusing: so many tests, conditions, etc. can be overwhelming when first learning these. I just usually check first for absolute convergence. If the series with the absolute values of terms converges, you are done. If not, we don't know yet. If it passes the alternating test, then you can say, yes, converges.

Comment: So if something converges absolutely it has to converge without absolute values?

Comment: @Clement provides a nice summary. I'd only add that while it is *true* that absolute convergence implies convergence, don't mistakenly conclude that "absolute divergence" implies divergence. That last sentence does not follow. If a $\sum |a_n|$ diverges, then we need to consider whether $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally.

Comment: Not quite John: if a series converges with absolute values, it converges absolutely. If it does not converge with absolute values, it might still converge, but conditionally, as with this series.

Comment: @John: absolute convergence implies convergence, yes.
You can prove it with the triangle inequality, using (carefully) the partial sums $\sum_{n=k}^m a_n$, since $$\left| \sum_{n=k}^m a_n\right| \leq \sum_{n=k}^m \left|a_n\right|$$.
In brief: absolute convergence (ACV) implies convergence CV. CV does not imply ACV. Importantly, as amWhy points out, we also have that absolute divergence ("not ACV") does not imply divergence ("not CV").

Comment: @amWhy: Have you ever noticed that you have not asked the 4th question?

Answer (score 2):

Everything in the question makes sense EXCEPT "so $\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ should also diverge".  That's wrong.  It is NOT TRUE that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$.

Comment: Regardless the limit is the same in both cases.

Comment: If you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, it is true that that is the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|$ in cases in which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: @John: what do you mean? $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$ both converge, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=2$, while $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:     +1 thanks for the edit you did for my answer. Thanks for the time. :)